# TortoiseSVN - Moved Working Copy no longer recognised

Tags: tortoisesvn, working-directory

I recently had to reinstall Windows and had several working copies checked out. I copied these to a network share, reinstalled Windows and copied the working copy folders back to the HDD.

They are now no longer recognised by TorroiseSVN as being a working copy - no overlay icons are present and the right-click menu shows `SVN Checkout` instead of `SVN Commit` and `SVN Update`

All `_svn` directories where backed up and restored.

What has gone wrong and how can I fix it without having to checkout fresh copies? (each one is nearly 1GB)

**Edit 1** Current installed TortoiseSVN is 1.7.4. The working copies would have been generated by 1.6.x and upgraded to 1.7.x. I think this is why they have `_svn` not `.svn` folders.

**Edit 2** These are definitely 1.7.x working copies as there is only a single `_svn` folder in the root and none in sub directories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: if you're not still using VS.NET (no, not VS2002: the version before that), then do yourself a favor and do a fresh checkout. Even if each working copy is around 1GB, believe me: it's worth it!

Otherwise, if your really don't want a fresh checkout:
You reinstalled windows, which means you lost the `SVN_ASP_DOT_NET_HACK` environment variable. You can manually set that env variable and set it to `1`. After a reboot, your working copies with the `_svn` folders instead of the `.svn` folders will be recognized by any svn client.

Comment: Ah! Now that rings a bell. I remember setting that env variable a loooooong time ago. Now using VS 2008 (for SSRS and DTSX) and VS 2010 (for everything else) so will annoy my network admin by re-checking out. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Does the right-click show an "upgrade local copy" option? If so, you have installed a 1.7 TortoiseSVN client, and you were on 1.6 or earlier before the machine swap. perform the upgrade and you should be ok.

Comment: No upgrade option. These were initially 1.6 copies but the upgrade to 1.7 was performed before the reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

The _svn instead of .svn is used when you're working with .NET Framework solution/project. Why don't you first try to use the exact same TortoiseSVN version wich you worked with before the reinstall?

Comment: I am using the same version. Started at 1.6, upgraded to 1.7, reinstalled Windows, reinstalled 1.7

Comment: So you are saying the .svn directories are not working and th _svn are?

Comment: newly checked out copies using 1.7 with `.svn` work fine. Copies which were checked out with 1.6 and have `_svn` which were then upgraded to 1.7 before the reinstall of windows don't work.